# Install nginx from jessie-backports updates openssl to 1.0.2k but openssl version -v shows 1.0.1t

Tags: nginx, debian, openssl

I am using Debian 8.7 64 bit on a vserver for testing.

I installed nginx via

`apt-get update -y && apt-get -t jessie-backports install nginx` and

`nginx -v` shows `nginx version: nginx/1.10.3`.

I also checkend the openssl version via `openssl version -v` and got

`OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)` as result.

Currently I have a problem with a productive server because I get lots off `failed (SSL: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init)` errors and found out that nginx and openssl had some problems when using 1.9 version of nginx. The productive system still uses nginx/1.9.10.

Before I want to update nginx to 1.10 via jessie-backports I want to test if everything is still working. While testing I also checked the version of openssl and got the info I pasted above. What does that mean? Is openssl 1.0.1t or 1.0.2k installed?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349798/how-to-distinguish-which-version-of-openssl-is-installed

To make it short:

`openssl` is the frontend, the command line interface.

`libssl1.0.0` is the backend, the library that is used from nginx (or other programs).

When using `openssl version -v` it shows the version of the cli and the library. The cli can have a different version than the library but it should be mentioned that it's better when both have the same version.

The error mentioned went away when updating `nginx` to 1.10.